# VHDL edge detection

Tags: vhdl

I want to detect the edges on the serial data signal (din). I have written the following code in VHDL which is running successfully but the edges are detected with one clock period delay i.e change output is generated with one clk_50mhz period delay at each edge. Could anyone please help me to detect edges without delay. Thank you.

```
 process (clk_50mhz)
 begin
        if clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1' then
            if (rst = '0') then
                shift_reg <= (others => '0');
            else
                shift_reg(1) <= shift_reg(0);
                shift_reg(0) <= din;    
                        end if;      
        end if;
 end process;

    process (clk_50mhz)
    begin
        if clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1' then
            if rst = '0' then
                change <= '0' ;
            elsif(clk_enable_2mhz = '1') then
                change <= shift_reg(0) xor shift_reg(1);                    
            end if ;
        end if ;
    end process ;
```

When I changed my code to following I am able to detect the edges

```
 process (clk_50mhz)
begin
    if clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1' then
        if (RST = '0') then
            shift_reg <= (others=>'0');
        else
            shift_reg(1) <= shift_reg(0);
            shift_reg(0) <= din;    
  end if;     
    end if;
end process;

change <= shift_reg(1) xor din;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity double_edge_detector is
    port ( 
        clk_50mhz   : in std_logic;
        rst         : in std_logic;
        din         : in std_logic;
        change      : out std_logic
    );
end double_edge_detector;

architecture bhv of double_edge_detector is

signal din_delayed1 :std_logic;

begin
    process(clk_50mhz)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_50mhz) then
            if rst = '1' then
                din_delayed1 <= '0';
            else
                din_delayed1 <= din;
            end if;
        end if;

    end process;

    change <= (din_delayed1 xor din); --rising or falling edge (0 -> 1 xor 1 -> 0)


end bhv;
```

Comment: Note that the solutions offered on that page are for detecting either rising or falling edges, but not both.

Comment: Thank you for the code Passepartout. I would like to detect both rising and falling edges. When I implemented the code you suggested din_delayed1 is same as din so there is no change.

Comment: What do you mean din_delayed1 is the same as din? They are 1 clock cycle apart.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am able to detect edges when I modified my code to the one I mentioned above.

Comment: @TomiJunnila How do you modify the code above to make it work for both conditions?

Comment: @Unknown123 The code above detects both rising and falling edges (as it compares whether the delayed value is the same as the current value). The answer originally had a link to a web page that only detected one or the other (based on the comments in the edit history, the link is now dead anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a combinatorial process to detect the difference without incurring extra clock cycle delays. (You will still need one register to delay the input as well.)

```
DELAY: process(clk_50mhz)
begin
    if clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1' then
        din_reg <= din;
    end if;
end process;

change <= din xor din_reg;
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be done in combinational logic. He could just do `if din_reg /= din` in the process statement.

Comment: You don't specify what kind of process you mean, but if he does `if din_reg /= din` in a clocked process, that causes the output to be active one clock cycle after the rising edge. If the process is not clocked, it is combinatory and is essentially equal to the statement I used.

Comment: That depends on how your "change" signal is used. If it is read inside of another clocked process, the timing would be the same as if you used `if din_reg /= din` in a clocked process.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I implement the above code then the change is '0' all the time.

Comment: Can you get a waveform diagram of `clk_50mhz`, `din`, `din_reg` and `change`? `change` shouldn't remain '0' unless there are no edges on `din`.

Comment: Thank you Tomic Junnila for the help. Yes, I got the waveform but there was no change but when I modified my code to the one I mentioned above I am able to detect the edges.